Isomorphism between tangent and cotangent bundle induced by a symplectic 2-form on the cotangent bundle
Some class notes I am studying are saying the following:

The cotangent bundle $M = T^∗S$ of a natural Lagrangian system $S$ has a natural symplectic manifold structure with the $2$-form $\omega=d(\sum_{i=1}^{l}p_i\mathrm{d}q_i)$.


$\omega$ induces an isomorphism between the tangent space $T_sS$ and the cotangent space $T^∗S$ to $S$ at any point $s \in S$. Indeed, it is enough to associate with every vector $v \in T_sS$ the covector $\omega(v, ·)$. If the chosen system of local coordinates $(p, q)$ of $T^*S$ is such that $\omega=\sum_{i=1}^{l}\mathrm{d}p_i\wedge\mathrm{d}q_i)$, the representative matrix of the isomorphism is the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0 & -I \\I & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

I don't see how I can plug $v \in T_sS$ inside $\omega$, which on each point $p$ of $T^*S$ defines a function of two elements of the tangent space $T_p(T^*S)$.
Also, the Hamilton equations recasted in the form $\dot x = J \mathrm{d}H(x)$ seem to me to express a correspondence between $T(T^*S)$ and $T^*(T^*S)$.
Any clue?

I believe there is a (serious) typo. The symplectic form on $M$ induces an isomorphism $T_pM\cong T^*_pM$ for every point $p\in M$.

What do you mean by $T_s(T^*s)$? It looks confusing as in the unbracketed term you are using $s$ as a point of the manifold $S$ but in the bracketed term, you are taking its tangent. Did you mean to write $T_s(T^*S)$? This doesn't work either as $s$ is not a point $T^*S$

@MoziburUllah thanks I have amended it

What is a Lagrangian system? As @TedShifrin says, if $X$ is a smooth manifold and $Y = T^*X$, then there is a naturally defined symplectic form $\omega$ on $Y$ (and not $X$). You can use $\omega$ to define a map from $$L: T_yY\rightarrow T_y^*Y$$ as follows: Given $v \in T_Y$, let $$L_v: T_yY \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ be the function given by $$L_v(w) = \omega(v,w).$$ In your question it appears that $S$ plays the role of $X$ here and $M = T^*S$ plays the role of $Y$.

@Deane it's from an Analytical Mechanics course. It defines a natural Lagrangian system as a mechanical system subject to ideal constraints, frictionless, fixed and holonomous, and subject to conservative forces. Its space of configurations is a differentiable manifold S of dimension l (the number of degrees of freedom of the system) and the Lagrangian L is a real function defined on the tangent bundle of S, L : TS → R

Thanks. Then what @TedShifrin and I wrote are correct.
